# Extract year from string, check if successful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I would like to check whether a year was found within a string. Something like

```
if string.scan(/\d{4}/).first == TRUE
```

for example a string looks like "there were 3 earthquakes in 2007"

Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of year? Or any 4 subsequent digits?

Comment: Please can you provide some examples of the data you are parsing. Without context in the data it's impossible to provide a solution. If you used the above on the following it would trigger false positives: 'The code to the safe is 0034'. or 'we should meet up are 0800 for coffee'

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response! In my case false positives are not that big of a problem since I expect them not to occur due to the nature of the data. I updated my code to give an example of the data I parse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match standalone 4 digit string, you may consider a regex with word boundaries:

```
!('It is 2016 now.' =~ /\b\d{4}\b/).nil? # => true
```

or - a more real world sample usage:

```
if string =~ /\b\d{4}\b/
```

The `\b\d{4}\b` matches any 4 digits that are not preceded nor followed with word characters (digits, letters or underscore), so there will be no match in `02312345`.

Also, in case you want to precise to current century, or the 20th century, you may use  `/\b(?:19|20)\d{2}\b/` regex.

To extract the digits, use `s[/\b\d{4}\b/]`.

```
'It was in 2015/16.'[/\b\d{4}\b/] # => 2015
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/vwJGrB)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is great! How would I include the case where I have a year as "2014/15" and I want to extract only "2014" ?

Comment: Thank you very much! Do I still use the .scan ? i.e. .scan(s[/\b\d{4}\b/])?

Comment: See https://ideone.com/Md0Msr: `"1948, 2945 and 3456 are years here.".scan(/\b\d{4}\b/)` -> `1948`, `2945`, `3456`

Comment: Note that you can omit `!` and `.nil?` in an `if` clause, i.e. `if string =~ /\b\d{4}\b/` works just as well.

Comment: @Stefan Yeah, I just wanted to output similar to *TRUE* :) I edited the answer to include this way of using the regex.